# Como configurar o VS Code para executar programas JAVA com MAVEN passando parâmetros?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Tenho um código sem método principal. O projeto é executado usando o seguinte comando:

```
$mvn clean install -Dparam1="folder" -Dparam2="path"
```

No Eclipse ou IntelliJ, eu só preciso criar um executor Maven, definir os objetivos como `clean installation` e passar os parâmetros do maven no lugar certo.

No VSCode, vi três abordagens diferentes e as experimentei:

1. Criando um arquivo `launch.json` chamando o comando `mvn` em `preLaunchTask`.

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        ...
        "preLaunchTask": "mvnDebug",
        "vmArgs": [ "clean", "install", "-Dparam1=\"blabla\"", "-Dparam2=\"blablabla\"" ]

    }
  ]
}
```

Eu tentei também passar todos os comandos em `prelaunchTask` sem o parâmetro `vmArgs`. E não funcionou.

2. Criação de um `task.json` passando o script, e um `launch.json` que irá chamar em `prelaunchTask` a tarefa criada com o nome definido no parâmetro`"taskName"`da tarefa.

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "Debug",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
```

E o `tasks.json`:

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Debug",
            "type": "java",
            "script": "mvnDebug clean install -Dparam1=\"folderName\" -Dparam2=\"blablabla\"",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

A terceira abordagem que usei é por meio de `settings.json`:

```js
{
    "maven.terminal.favorites": [
        {
            "alias": "CLEAN COMPILE",
            "command": "clean install -Dparam1=\"value\" -Dparam2=\"blabla\"",
            "debug": true
        },
    ]
}
```

Para todos eles obtive o resultado em terminal:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 56787
```

O que eu preciso é:

1. O que isso significa? Por que está esperando por um porto? Como o VSCode usa um soquete para fazer isso?
2. Qual é a melhor abordagem e por quê?
3. Como rodar meu código no VSCode? Este é o mais importante! Eu preciso executar meu código.